# Dictionary-style paragraphs

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, line-spacing

Is there a way to write a dictionary using LaTeX: that is, how do you construct the shape of the paragraphs so that they look like so-called hanging paragraphs and that there is a certain spacing between them, i.e. two dictionary entries?

Comment: Yes but this question is really too broad for this format, and could be closed for that reason. You can use a latex list with suitable settings for indent or you can (with care) use the tex primitives `\hangindent` and `\parskip`. But not all dictionaries use the same style so you really need to ask a question about a specific layout.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58218/586 may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Here [Typesetting a Dictionary with LaTeX](http://www.mengensatz.de/blog/?p=69) you can find some code and discussion about this kind of work with LaTeX.

Comment: Link seems to be broken.